# PhantomJS font rendering problems when generating PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, phantomjs, adobe

I am using 2.0 build of PhantomJS and I render my HTML's to PDF. However, my fonts were looking very narrow and like glued together. I tried to give proper letter-spacing property to elements but then I realized that it is not a css or font issue, but an issue that is **specific when creating PDF**. I have no problem rendering to PNG.

So here is the original html that I use (I removed html tags, it was causing problems with the editor). I created the font-face with fontsquirrel using arial.ttf from Windows fonts folder.

```
<head>
    <title>Trial</title>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'arialregular';
            src: url('arial-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
                 url('arial-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
                 url('arial-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            letter-spacing: normal;
        }
        body {
            color: #000000;
            font-family: arialregular, sans-serif;
            margin-left: 15px;
            margin-top: 15px;
            font-size: 9pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</body>
```

I use rasterize.js to create png and pdf. Here is the png result, which is expected and have no problems.

```
phantomjs.exe rasterize.js my.html my.png a4
```

[image: Arial font rendered correctly.]

Arial font is rendered correctly. When I generate pdf using

```
phantomjs.exe rasterize.js my.html my.pdf a4
```

it generates the pdf without any error. And here is how it looks like just after opening it on Adobe PDF (not reader). When clicked to the container notice that there is no font shown.

[image: No fonts shown.]

When I click in the element to edit it, but without doing any edit and just putting the cursor, it shows me an embed font.

[image]

Looks like it tries to embed the font to the pdf, but it fails as the size of PDF is 6kb when font's is about half a MB.

When I commit to edit, like writing a space etc, it shows me the following error and falls back to Minion Pro.
[image]

You will be asking why I do not use just Arial as it is available, and I did all those above to debug the issue: Same happens to Arial. So when I change the css from above to this:

```
        body {
            color: #000000;
            font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
            margin-left: 15px;
            margin-top: 15px;
            font-size: 9pt;
            width: 21.5cm;
        }
```

the PNG renders the same, without problems. The PDF, however, shows **Arial** when clicked, but when I try to edit it gives the same error saying **Arial is not available** and it falls back to Minion Pro again.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You probably should report an issue : https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues

Comment: Are you actually embedding (or referencing) the font that you think you have? The Acrobat error suggests that the "f121t4h3-49l-d7t-21pxhl7ozzyr8" name is corrupted, so Acrobat uses Minion Pro instead. Your Arial reference works, but Acrobat cannot find that in your machine resources. 

If you press Ctrl+D to bring up the Document Properties, what does Acrobat show for font info? What does its Pre-flight PDF Syntax analyzer show for "f121t4h3-49l-d7t-21pxhl7ozzyr8" font information? Do you find an AdobeFnt*.lst resource file created in the folder where your font resources are residing?

Comment: Any progress on this issue?

Comment: @Karl2011 not yet. Downgrading solves this problem, but we had other issues with downgrading because of other missing features. Currently we are using it that way, users do not care/notice the issue for more than a year.